# Limit how many times Contact can re-enter Journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am working on building a journey where the Entry Source is Salesforce Data. Whenever a Contact gets loaded to a specific campaign in Salesforce they will enter Journey, receive a single email and exit. The requirement from the business is that they only want a single customer to receive this communication three times. What design options do I have to cap how many times they can re-enter this journey at 3?

Answer (score 1):

If you're set on the entry source being Salesforce data, you have potentially a bigger conundrum to consider...the only way to re-enter a person into an existing Campaign is to delete the old Campaign Member record and then add them again, but that's not really how Campaigns are supposed to work.
The easiest way to do what you want (as long as you're comfortable with the above) might be to add a hidden custom field onto the Contact object that is specific to this campaign and counts the number of times the contact is entered into the Campaign (so you'd control the counter with a process in CRM). You could then either:

1. Use that hidden contact field getting updated to trigger the journey in Marketing Cloud and put on a filter for if the number is less than 4; or
2. Use the Campaign to trigger the journey and include the counter in the journey entry source. Once again you'd filter the contacts out when this number is above 3 so they don't receive the email

I would say neither option is particularly pretty (because you're adding a campaign-specific semi-redundant field to the Contact object), but would theoretically work. I would potentially be looking at the solution as a whole (as in using a CRM Campaign at all) and seeing if there is a better solution to do what you need.